# Nonconsecutive attempts to trap a pet

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When pet battling in WoW, I often find myself trying to capture new level 25 pets in Warlords of Draenor. These wild pets do the most damage, being level 25. My normal pet team is built for self-healing and effectiveness against most common wild pets (e.g. critters, beasts, flying). However, they still take quite a beating at times.

Let us assume I attempt to trap a wild pet several turns in a row without success. While this is going on, the enemy pet is beating up my pet. I take a break to use my pet's healing ability, then continue attempting to trap.

Does the cumulative bonus to trapping reset after taking a one-turn break to heal (or swap pets), or does it pick up where it left off?

Scenario 1:

1. trap: 40% chance
2. trap: 40% * 1.25 = 50% chance
3. Take a turn to heal or swap pets
4. trap: 50% * 1.25 = 63% chance
5. trap: 63% * 1.25 = 78% chance

Scenario 2:

1. trap: 40% chance
2. trap: 40% * 1.25 = 50% chance
3. Take a turn to heal or swap pets
4. trap: 40% chance
5. trap: 40% * 1.25 = 50% chance

Note: base trap chance is unknown, see [strong trap](http://www.wowhead.com/petability=77).

Based on my own memory and bias, I am leaning toward scenario 2. However, I am curious to know if there is a definitive answer. In the end, this helps determine if it is worth it to chance trapping at low health given good chances and those chances resetting, or if it does not matter and playing it safe has no downside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the wording of the ability I would presume that the capture chance does not reset if you take a turn off to heal your pets etc.

The wording of the [traps](http://www.wowhead.com/petability=135/pristine-trap) says that capture chance is increased ***each time you fail***, not for each consecutive attempt.

Though I have no good evidence to confirm this, nor have I seen any actual evidence either way. My own experience has not really shown a clear pattern either.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the pet battle is in progress your % stays the same.  However Scenario 1 is supported by many other WoWHeads in many Communities.

Comment: Do you have a link to something more definitive to support that assertion?